# How to stop jQuery dialogs from overlapping?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-dialog

I have found that when multiple jQuery dialogs are open on a page, they are prone to overlapping.

How would I stop this, either by a built-in jQuery UI feature, or a custom bit of code?

Comment: what's with the downvote

Comment: You need to be a bit elaborate! `:)` Add some code to your question and see if the downvote is removed!

Comment: You may want to look at [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or search for jquery collision detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the **CSS** `z-index` value for each modal window. Eg., you have invoked three modal windows at a time, each of them will have a common `class` and a unique `id`. Say this way:

```
<div class="jqui-modal" id="firstModal">
...
</div>

<div class="jqui-modal" id="secondModal">
...
</div>
```

Now you can choose which one to be first. Say, I want the `#firstModal` to be on top of `#secondModal`, the you can use this **bit** of CSS code:

```
#firstModal {z-index: 1599;}
#secondModal {z-index: 1500;}
```

If you want all the modal windows to be appearing on the same co-ordinates, try this:

```
.jqui-modal {z-index: 1600;} /* One single Z-Index for all */
```

Comment: But then they would be overlapping. I guess OP wants them to play nicely with each other and align NEXT to each other

Comment: @mplungjan Hmm yeah, I have messed up with the question. Updated now.

Comment: Ad if you want them to always be NEXT to each other, pushing each other to the side when they share the same space?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `z-index;` property to show the stacked dialogs as how to want to display them.